# Is additional isolation needed for inverter control circuitry?

Tags: isolation, digital-communications, dali

I'm currently setting up a PV island system. Electricity is stored in two parallel 12V batteries which is then fed into a 300W 230V inverter. The load connected to the inverter consists out of several industrial LED lamps which can be controlled over [DALI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface). An additional DALI-controller is used, which dimms the lamps over a simple 0-10V interface. The inverter also has a two pin connector exposed which can be used to manually shut it off.

I'm in the process of developing a microcontroller based system which controls the inverter over the remote pins and also the LED lamps.

It is clear to me that the secondary side (230V) is galvanically isolated from the primary side (12V) through the inverter's transformer.

However, I see two options on how to connect my circuitry:

1. Use digital isolators for communication with the DALI controller and an additional SELV 24V power supply plugged in to the 230V side. This ensures that both sides stay isolated.
2. Directly drive the DALI controller without isolation. This connects the 12V side with the ELV side of the DALI bus. It seems that the DALI lines only have basic isolation.

With normal mains AC, I see the risk of having 230V AC on the DALI lines in case of a fault which can lead to damage and/or shock. But I'm not sure if that is a risk in my inverter system.

What isolation (if any) would you recommend in this situation?

Edit: Added Diagram
[image: System Diagram]

Comment: Can you provide a diagram of your system?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post. I hope that helps. The diagram shows option 1 described in my post. Question is, if that's the way to go or if I can cut the digital isolation as well as the 24V PS and directly supply everything from my control circuitry.

Comment: without a in depth analysis... I would connect that 8-36V in to the existing 24V and do some isolated solution for the "2 Pin Remote Con", guess you can do it with optocouplers

Comment: That sounds good but I'm missing out on galvanic isolation for the DALI bus. If I connect both grounds, the DALI controller "sees" the 12V battery side which in return poses a risk as the whole system can be exposed to 230V incase of a fault. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: wouldn't a PELV Power supply replacing your suggested SELV supply do the trick? By the way, is there not a kind of isolation in the LED lamps?

Comment: so I just looked up dali-bus, and its stated, that its galvanic isolated by definition. So you are using shelf products, then there should be isolation between DALI Controler and LED's...Or?

Comment: maybe page 4 is of interest for you http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/atmel-42071-dali-slave-reference_design_application-note_at01244.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure if PELV helps here, as the whole system is not grounded at all as protection against electrical shock should be sufficient through the inverter's isolated AC. I'm more worried about damaged equipment and possible hazards when the rest of the system is exposed to 230V. According to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface#Eigenschaften the digital interface is only protected with basic insulation and not to SELV-standards. Thats the thing which worries me a bit.

Comment: Yes, I read that to. Think you are right, PELV is not what you want. so are there any touchable parts (metal) when in operation? Guess you to put power supply, DALI Controller and stuff in a nice housing made of plastic, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_gland and secure cables... then it should be save to operate...Or?

Comment: My plan is to put everything in a safe enclosure so that should be fine. Just for clarification, what could happen if the 230V potential connects to battery plus? After my understanding, there is no current (or only minimal) that can flow as the potential is isolated and floating. But are there any real-world risks in this scenario? Can this still lead to distruction or possible malfunction of the batteries?

Comment: Think you are right, it should not cause any major issues as long as only one of the AC conductors has contact with the other side

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would run the DALI circuit on a grounded DC supply, the grounding gives you protection in the event of a failure of the basic isolation. and makes it safe and easy to probe voltages and signals.

This may require fuses to prevent large fault currents from entering the DALI bus

Once you get the grounded system working you may want to consider changing it to an isolated system using enclosures and controls that
have reinforced insulation.